# swagger-ui.html shows a blank page in a Vaadin + Spring application

Tags: java, spring, swagger, vaadin

In my Spring+Vaadin (18) application I configured this:

```
vaadin.url-mapping=/ui/*
```

All Vaadin views are indeed accessible with a "localhost:8080/ui/something" address.

In the pom I have the required dependency for the Swagger UI:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But the swagger-ui page returns full blank with the following console output by browsing to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html which automatically redirects to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html/?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config.

[image]

The OpenAPI JSON page is accessible on http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/

[image]

Any idea why the Swagger UI page is not shown?

Comment: In v14, Swagger UI works like a charm. Not sure what's the problem with v18

Comment: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10163